# How to make brick texture appear bumpy

Tags: normal-map, bump

Which node should I add to this material to make the structure appear bumpy (mortar inset relative to the bricks)?

[image: screenshot]

I tried various combinations like `[Brick Texture] Fac > [Bump] Normal > Normal [BSDF]` and `[Brick Texture] Fac > [Bump] Normal > Displacement [Material Output]` and `[Brick Texture] Fac > Strength [Normal map] Normal > Normal [BSDF]` and so on, but I didn't find one that had any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bump node converts a height to a normal map by reading grayscale gradients. If the height map is too sharp there isn't anything to create surface angle shifts.

Increase the mortar smooth to get a broader gradient at the brick edges

[image]

Comment: Oh, ok. Now I see that both the Bump and Displacement node only change the color of the object. Makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

[Jackdaw's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/147975/11512) is good if you only want it to *appear* bumpy, but there is actually a way to *make* it bumpy, but it **only works with the Cycles rendering engine**.

Connect the Brick Texture to the *Displacement* input of the Material Output (possibly passing it through another Displacement node) and then in the Material Properties under *Settings* set *Displacement* to "Displacement and Bump":

[image: screenshot]